# Using Three.js STL loader with angular

Tags: angular, three.js

i'm trying to get a simple canvas to load a simple stl file on an angular project and don't seem to be able to get this to work...

I tried many guides and nothing seem to work. when  using native javascript with the same kind of code it works perfectly.

I have a canvas with a viewchild: `<canvas #myCanvas></canvas>` in my html.

In my .ts file:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';
var OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)
var STLLoader = require('three-stl-loader')(THREE)
var loader = new STLLoader()
import Scene = THREE.Scene;
import Mesh = THREE.Mesh;
import PerspectiveCamera = THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
import WebGLRenderer = THREE.WebGLRenderer;
import TrackballControls = THREE.TrackballControls;
import {log} from "util";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.myCanvas.nativeElement.style.background = "grey";
    this.myCanvas.nativeElement.style.width="1000px"
    this.myCanvas.nativeElement.style.height="500px"
  }

  @ViewChild("myCanvas") myCanvas;
  private scene: Scene;
  private camera: PerspectiveCamera;
  private renderer: WebGLRenderer;
  private controls: TrackballControls;
  title = 'app works!';
  constructor(){
    this.init3D();
  }
  init3D(){
    log("init3D")
    // renderer
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, canvas: this.myCanvas});
    log(""+window.innerWidth+" "+ window.innerHeight )
    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    // scene
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF );

    // camera
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10000 );

    this.camera.position.set( 113, 111, 113 );
    this.scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

    this.scene.add( this.camera ); // required, because we are adding a light as a child of the camera

    // controls
    this.controls = OrbitControls;

    // lights

    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    this.camera.add( light );

    loader.load('./assets/plate.stl', geometry => {
      var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
      log(this.scene.toJSON())
      this.scene.add(mesh)
    })

    this.animate();

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.onWindowResize, false );
  }

  animate() {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(_ => this.animate());

    this.camera.lookAt( this.scene.position );

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

  }

  onWindowResize() {

    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  }

}
```

I get no errors but there is nothing in my canvas when the page finish to load.
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it to run, i'm posting a working code if some one will need it in the future.

The problem was my canvas wasn't initialized yet, when i moved the 3d initialization to "ngAfterViewInit" it worked.

to use the code you have to run this installs:

```
npm i --save three
npm i @types/three --save-dev 
npm i --save three-stl-loader
npm i --save three-orbit-controls
```

in the .html file:

```
<canvas #myCanvas></canvas>
```

in the .ts file:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, OnInit, Renderer2, Input} from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';
var OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)
var STLLoader = require('three-stl-loader')(THREE)
var loader = new STLLoader()
import Scene = THREE.Scene;
import Mesh = THREE.Mesh;
import PerspectiveCamera = THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
import WebGLRenderer = THREE.WebGLRenderer;
import TrackballControls = THREE.TrackballControls;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stl-loader',
  templateUrl: './stl-loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stl-loader.component.css']
})
export class StlLoaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("myCanvas") myCanvas:any;
  @Input()
  private path:string;
  private scene: Scene;
  private camera: PerspectiveCamera;
  private renderer: WebGLRenderer;
  private controls: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //add listener for the resize of the window - will resize the renderer to fit the window
    let global = this.render.listen('window', 'resize', (evt) => {
      this.onWindowResize();
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.init3D();
  }
  constructor(private render: Renderer2){

  }
  init3D(){
    // renderer
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, canvas:  this.myCanvas.nativeElement});
    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    // scene
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF );

    // camera
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10000 );
    this.camera.position.set( 113, 111, 113 );
    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );
    this.scene.add( this.camera ); // required, because we are adding a light as a child of the camera

    // controls
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera,this.renderer.domElement);

    // lights
    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    this.camera.add( light );

    loader.load(this.path, geometry => {
      var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xBEBEBE } );

      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      this.scene.add(mesh)
    })

    //request animation
    this.animate();

  }

  /**
   * render the scene and request the window animation frame
   */
  animate() {

    this.camera.lookAt( this.scene.position );

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(_ => this.animate());

  }

  /**
   * will resize the renderer and the camera to the right size of the window
   */
  onWindowResize() {

    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  }

}
```

the path to the STL file is given as an input to the component.

Raz

Answer (score 0):

[ng-three-template](https://github.com/JohnnyDevNull/ng-three-template)
This dude created a template for angular + three.

using that template, you can easily:

`import {STLLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader';`